# How to add 'greater' filter to every 'minimum' value in a result pane column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, min

I have the following syntax:

```
SELECT t1.cardid, t1.Name, t2.record
FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 on t1.tag=t2.tag GROUP BY t1.cardid, t1.name
```

the result come out like this:

```
cardid      name       record
100         Dan        09:00
100         Dan        10:00
200         Jane       06:00
200         Jane       09:00
399         Lisa       07:00
399         Lisa       13:00
500         Kane       10:00
500         Kane       12:10
500         Kane       13:50
```

Now I add a 'min' filter and modify the syntax to become like this:

```
SELECT t1.cardid, t1.Name, min(t2.record) As Record
FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 on t1.tag=t2.tag GROUP BY t1.cardid, t1.name
```

The result become like this:

```
cardid      name       record
100         Dan        09:00
200         Jane       06:00
399         Lisa       07:00
500         Kane       10:00
```

How do I add a filter so that only the 'minimum value' of each record that has more than; say '08:00' value come out in the "record" column. The result I want is something like this:

```
cardid      name       record
100         Dan        09:00
500         Kane       10:00
```

I'm using SQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.cardid, t1.Name, min(t2.record) As Record
FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 on t1.tag=t2.tag
GROUP BY t1.cardid, t1.name
having min(t2.record) >= cast('08:00' as time)
```

I suppose record is also [time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/time.html) type, also you can use `convert('08:00', time)` or even try without cast/convert, it can work too, as mysql can do automatic casting

for very old mysql you can try to use `having 0+substring(t2.record, 1,2) >= 8`